# Why can't my localhost view .png files

Tags: apache, get, localhost, http-status-code-403

```
      <img src="images/green_counter_top.png" />
       //vs
      <img src="images/background.jpg" />
```

My local host is blocking any attempt to access a .png image. However I can access the jpg. I'm stumped, any ideas on why this is happening?

GET http://localhost/sandbox/red_counter_top.png 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: 403 Forbidden HTTP status code indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action. Check if there is any setting which is only allowing *.jpg. It should allow *.*.

Comment: Maybe there are different file permissions active for the two files?